# Countif, Countifs or IF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a bit lost with a formula, I'm not sure which is the best to us for the below.

I have BU_Description for each for each document type.

```
PPForm      , Employment_Agreement, ID      , POR, BU_Description
Not Received, Received            , Received,Received, HR
Not Received, Received            , Received,Received, warehouse
Not Received, Not Received        , Received,Received, warehouse
Not Received, Received            , Received,Received, HR
```

I need to run a count for each BU_Description how many documents were received.

**Example**

```
BU_Description , PPFORM                        ,Employment_Agreement          , ID         ,
  HR           , Received "0" Not Received "4" , Received "2" Not Received "0", Received "2" Not Received "0",
```

[image]

Result 
[image]

Comment: its not too clear what you're trying to achieve dude

Comment: @DougCoats, I want to count for each BU how many PPF for were received, and how many were not received. the data is all in 1 sheet, and the report is in a breakdown.

Comment: Here is an example of solution:
`="Received "&COUNTIFS(A:A, "Received", E:E, "HR")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Formula in `H3` filled to right and downwards:

```
=COUNTIFS($E:$E,$G3,INDEX($A:$E,,INT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)/2)+1),H$2)
```

Comment: its workig perfectly, now to change it to the data in another sheet, and the report in sheet breakdown. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh then you can drop a SUM formula anywhere on the sheet you'd like, and just double up the efforts. 1 for received & one for not recieved. you probably can use a "totals" row at the bottom.

```
=SUM(range)
```

Comment: its worht nothing that you SUM range can look like this : =SUM(a2,a5,a8) etc